# How to build a thread-safe Request Handler with Python Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

Does Tornado make any guarantees about how many requests are concurrently handled by a single RequestHandler?  I'm thinking about managing session data like this:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def prepare(self):
    self.session = load_session_from_memcached

  def get(self):
    # work with self.session

  def on_finish(self):
    save_session_to_memcached(self.session)
```

But this is only going to work if `self.session` in `get()` is the same as `self.session` in `prepare()`.  And that is only going to be true if a single RequestHandler processes at most one request concurrently.  Is this how Tornado works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RequestHandler`s are instantiated per request. A single request handler instance will serve one and only one request in its lifetime

---

Edit:

Here's the link to the part of the documentation which confirms my statement above:
http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#overriding-requesthandler-methods

See Item 1: A new RequestHandler object is created on each request

Comment: Thanks!  I received a similar response from the Tornado users mailing list, but SO wouldn't let me answer my own question.

Comment: This link is now obsolete (well, broken anyway - I'm not familiar enough w/ Tornado to say without some time absorbing).